# При переполнении страницы контентом, правый блок теряет высоту

Tags: css

Всем привет. Верстаю 2х-колоночный макет с прилепленным к низу экрана футером. Столкнулся с проблемой потери высоты блока `.aside` при переполнении контента в блоке `.content`. Никак не могу понять в чем причина такого поведения.

Уточняю - блок `.aside` при малом кол-ве контента в блоке .content должен заполнять всю высоту до footer'a.

Ссылка на проблему (просто добавьте контент): http://codepen.io/astor/pen/rrBdmy?editors=1100

```css
* {
  margin: 0;
  padding: 0;
  box-sizing: border-box;
}
body,
html {
  width: 100%;
  height: 100%;
}
.wrapper {
  display: table;
  width: 100%;
  height: 100%;
}
.main {
  display: table-row;
  height: 100%;
}
.aside {
  float: right;
  width: 300px;
  min-height: 100%;
  background: gold;
}
.content {
  padding-right: 320px;
  min-height: 100%;
  background: silver;
}
footer {
  background: red;
}
```

```html
<div class="wrapper">
  <div class="main">
    <div class="aside">Menu</div>
    <div class="content">
      Откуда он появился? Многие думают, что Lorem Ipsum - взятый с потолка псевдо-латинский набор слов, но это не совсем так.
    </div>
  </div>
  <footer>footer</footer>
</div>
```

Заранее спасибо.

Comment: Какой у вас обозреватель, Google Chrome? Проверил у себя — Chrome схлопывает высоту, но Internet Explorer 11 — нет; на других не проверял.

Comment: Хром, В Осле 11 такая-же ерунда, только-что проверил.

Comment: Странно... http://i.stack.imgur.com/FAFkw.png. У меня версия 11.0.9600.18314, KB3154070.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Добавь `overflow:auto` в `content`, и убери `padding-right`.

***Результат:***

```css
* {
  margin: 0;
  padding: 0;
  box-sizing: border-box;
}
body,
html {
  width: 100%;
  height: 100%;
}
.wrapper {
  display: table;
  width: 100%;
  height: 100%;
}
.main {
  display: table-row;
  height: 100%;
}
.aside {
  float: right;
  width: 300px;
  min-height: 100%;
  background: gold;
}
.content {
  min-height: 100%;
  background: silver;
  overflow: auto;
}
footer {
  background: red;
}
```

```html
<div class="wrapper">
  <div class="main">
    <div class="aside">Menu</div>
    <div class="content">
      Откуда он появился? Многие думают, что Lorem Ipsum - взятый с потолка псевдо-латинский набор слов, но это не совсем так. Его корни уходят в один фрагмент классической латыни 45 года н.э., то есть более двух тысячелетий назад. Ричард МакКлинток, профессор
      латыни из колледжа Hampden-Sydney, штат Вирджиния, взял одно из самых странных слов в Lorem Ipsum, "consectetur", и занялся его поисками в классической латинской литературе. В результате он нашёл неоспоримый первоисточник Lorem Ipsum в разделах
      1.10.32 и 1.10.33 книги "de Finibus Bonorum et Malorum" ("О пределах добра и зла"), написанной Цицероном в 45 году н.э. Этот трактат по теории этики был очень популярен в эпоху Возрождения. Первая строка Lorem Ipsum, "Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet..",
      происходит от одной из строк в разделе 1.10.32 Откуда он появился? Многие думают, что Lorem Ipsum - взятый с потолка псевдо-латинский набор слов, но это не совсем так. Его корни уходят в один фрагмент классической латыни 45 года н.э., то есть более
      двух тысячелетий назад. Ричард МакКлинток, профессор латыни из колледжа Hampden-Sydney, штат Вирджиния, взял одно из самых странных слов в Lorem Ipsum, "consectetur", и занялся его поисками в классической латинской литературе. В результате он нашёл
      неоспоримый первоисточник Lorem Ipsum в разделах 1.10.32 и 1.10.33 книги "de Finibus Bonorum et Malorum" ("О пределах добра и зла"), написанной Цицероном в 45 году н.э. Этот трактат по теории этики был очень популярен в эпоху Возрождения. Первая
      строка Lorem Ipsum, "Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet..", происходит от одной из строк в разделе 1.10.32Откуда он появился? Многие думают, что Lorem Ipsum - взятый с потолка псевдо-латинский набор слов, но это не совсем так. Его корни уходят в один фрагмент
      классической латыни 45 года н.э., то есть более двух тысячелетий назад. Ричард МакКлинток, профессор латыни из колледжа Hampden-Sydney, штат Вирджиния, взял одно из самых странных слов в Lorem Ipsum, "consectetur", и занялся его поисками в классической
      латинской литературе. В результате он нашёл неоспоримый первоисточник Lorem Ipsum в разделах 1.10.32 и 1.10.33 книги "de Finibus Bonorum et Malorum" ("О пределах добра и зла"), написанной Цицероном в 45 году н.э. Этот трактат по теории этики был
      очень популярен в эпоху Возрождения. Первая строка Lorem Ipsum, "Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet..", происходит от одной из строк в разделе 1.10.32Откуда он появился? Многие думают, что Lorem Ipsum - взятый с потолка псевдо-латинский набор слов, но это
      не совсем так. Его корни уходят в один фрагмент классической латыни 45 года н.э., то есть более двух тысячелетий назад. Ричард МакКлинток, профессор латыни из колледжа Hampden-Sydney, штат Вирджиния, взял одно из самых странных слов в Lorem Ipsum,
      "consectetur", и занялся его поисками в классической латинской литературе. В результате он нашёл неоспоримый первоисточник Lorem Ipsum в разделах 1.10.32 и 1.10.33 книги "de Finibus Bonorum et Malorum" ("О пределах добра и зла"), написанной Цицероном
      в 45 году н.э. Этот трактат по теории этики был очень популярен в эпоху Возрождения. Первая строка Lorem Ipsum, "Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet..", происходит от одной из строк в разделе 1.10.32Откуда он появился? Многие думают, что Lorem Ipsum - взятый
      с потолка псевдо-латинский набор слов, но это не совсем так. Его корни уходят в один фрагмент классической латыни 45 года н.э., то есть более двух тысячелетий назад. Ричард МакКлинток, профессор латыни из колледжа Hampden-Sydney, штат Вирджиния,
      взял одно из самых странных слов в Lorem Ipsum, "consectetur", и занялся его поисками в классической латинской литературе. В результате он нашёл неоспоримый первоисточник Lorem Ipsum в разделах 1.10.32 и 1.10.33 книги "de Finibus Bonorum et Malorum"
      ("О пределах добра и зла"), написанной Цицероном в 45 году н.э. Этот трактат по теории этики был очень популярен в эпоху Возрождения. Первая строка Lorem Ipsum, "Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet..", происходит от одной из строк в разделе 1.10.32Откуда
      он появился? Многие думают, что Lorem Ipsum - взятый с потолка псевдо-латинский набор слов, но это не совсем так. Его корни уходят в один фрагмент классической латыни 45 года н.э., то есть более двух тысячелетий назад. Ричард МакКлинток, профессор
      латыни из колледжа Hampden-Sydney, штат Вирджиния, взял одно из самых странных слов в Lorem Ipsum, "consectetur", и занялся его поисками в классической латинской литературе. В результате он нашёл неоспоримый первоисточник Lorem Ipsum в разделах
      1.10.32 и 1.10.33 книги "de Finibus Bonorum et Malorum" ("О пределах добра и зла"), написанной Цицероном в 45 году н.э. Этот трактат по теории этики был очень популярен в эпоху Возрождения. Первая строка Lorem Ipsum, "Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet..",
      происходит от одной из строк в разделе 1.10.32Откуда он появился? Многие думают, что Lorem Ipsum - взятый с потолка псевдо-латинский набор слов, но это не совсем так. Его корни уходят в один фрагмент классической латыни 45 года н.э., то есть более
      двух тысячелетий назад. Ричард МакКлинток, профессор латыни из колледжа Hampden-Sydney, штат Вирджиния, взял одно из самых странных слов в Lorem Ipsum, "consectetur", и занялся его поисками в классической латинской литературе. В результате он нашёл
      неоспоримый первоисточник Lorem Ipsum в разделах 1.10.32 и 1.10.33 книги "de Finibus Bonorum et Malorum" ("О пределах добра и зла"), написанной Цицероном в 45 году н.э. Этот трактат по теории этики был очень популярен в эпоху Возрождения. Первая
      строка Lorem Ipsum, "Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet..", происходит от одной из строк в разделе 1.10.32
    </div>
  </div>
  <footer>footer</footer>
</div>
```

Comment: Круто, спасибо. Как всегда оказалось все просто)))
А вообще, в чем причина такого поведения браузеров - при минимальном контенте гуд, при большом бэд?

Comment: @Astor Потому что float используете, этого на будущее лучше не делать. Постарайтесь отказываться от `float` и `position:relative` - много проблем могут создать, при неграмотном использовании.

Comment: Понял. Учту. Еще раз спасибо..

Comment: Еще один момент - если задать padding'и для .aside и .content, то между футером и блоками появляется лишний отступ. Как с ним бороться?

Comment: @Astor используйте для этих блоков вместо `height` --> `min-height` и для обоих `overflow:auto`, либо любой подходящий для вас, например `scroll`.

Comment: к сожалению не помогло

Answer (score 0):

если к .aside и .content добавить display: table-cell - все вроде нормально http://codepen.io/anon/pen/bwbKOy?editors=1100

```
.aside {
  width: 300px;
  background: gold;
  display: table-cell;
}

.content {
  display: table-cell;
  background: silver;
}
```

но проблемы с футером - его нужно выносить за .wrapper

И вообще я бы делал такие вещи с помощью flexbox